# f.check_box で出力される hidden field って何のため？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

タイトル通りなんですが

`f.check_box 'test'`

とかくと

```
<input name="test" type="hidden" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="test" id="test">
```

というHTMLが生成されます
１行目の hidden_field にはどういう意味があるのでしょうか

そもそも name の重複って HTML の規約的にOKなんでしょうか

Answer (score 2, accepted):

この例で言うと `test` が boolean の場合に、チェックを外したら `false` として値が保存されるように hidden フィールドが出力されてます。

**チェックを入れずに送信した場合:**
`value=0` だけが送られて boolean が false として保存される。

**チェックを入れて送信した場合:**
`value=0` と `value=1` のパラメータ両方が送られる。
サーバー側では後ろのパラメータで上書きして boolean は true になる。

もしも hidden フィールドが存在しない場合は、 `value=0` が送られることはないので、一度 true になったら false になることは無くなってしまいます。

Comment: なるほどです。チェックボックスってチェック入れてないとそもそもキー自体が送信されないんですね。